# Getting the PID of the process showing a particular window

Tags: java, applet, window, x11

I want to know the process ID of a particular window. I have seen and used the *Force close* panel applet, and I'd like something similar that would report me the process ID of the window I select.

If a tool for this purpose exists, that'd be great. Although, I am willing even to write a simple python script if it can be done.

**Edit**: In a more specific case, I want to get the process ID of a java swing window. (The `xprop` solution some answers suggest is not working).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `xprop _NET_WM_PID` and click the window you want to query.

For instance, if you run it on a gnome-terminal:

```
 $ xprop _NET_WM_PID
 _NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 2386
 $ pidof gnome-terminal
 2386
```

Comment: Thanks Egil, this seems to work for few windows, but I am trying on a java swing window, and the output comes as `_NET_WM_PID:  not found.` Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
xprop _NET_WM_PID | cut -d' ' -f3
```

That will give you a target, click a window and it'll give you the PID.

I'm sending the output through `cut` (you could use `awk '{ print $3 }'` instead if you like) to clean it up so you could script it into something else, if you needed to.

Comment: Please see my comment on Egil's answer, this does not work for java swing windows. Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could also open *System Monitor*. Switch to the Processes tab and look for your Java window.

Comment: All my java processes are listed as, well, `java` in that tab. How to know which process has opened which window? I couldn't find anything that shows this.