# How to get PID of shell running in a terminal window under mouse?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, window-manager, xdotool

Though similar questions asked before in this forum [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245428/how-to-know-the-pid-of-active-window) , [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508527/find-out-the-application-under-the-mouse)  and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36246/getting-the-pid-of-the-process-showing-a-particular-window), my question is different. I want to get PID of a running bash process in gnome terminal.

Note: Suggested link which posted by moderators doesn't provide any working solution. I don't understand people ignorantly vote for closing my topic.

Commands like

```
 xprop | awk '/PID/ {print $3}' | xargs ps h -o pid,cmd
 xprop _NET_WM_PID | cut -d' ' -f3
```

give me only **gnome-terminal** parent PID not bash process ID

If I run

```
 PID=$$; echo $PID
```

or

```
 cut -d ' ' -f 4 /proc/self/stat
```

gives me exact PID of terminal but I have to run  those commands in terminal to get the PID.

I have a script that toggles process of a terminal between `kill -STOP PID` and `kill -CONT PID` with a shortcut key combination.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    myid=$(ps $(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowpid) |tail -n 1 |awk '{print $3}')
    if [[ $myid == "Sl" ]]
    then
    kill -STOP `xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowpid`
    else
    kill -CONT `xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowpid`
    fi
```

As I mentioned the line 
`myid=$(ps $(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowpid) |tail -n 1 |awk '{print $3}')`

returns only PID of parent **gnome-terminal**

Is there a way to achieve what I want?
       `

EDIT: Beside Dmitry Alexandrov's answer, I also found another working solution 
here [How to know the pid of active window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245428/how-to-know-the-pid-of-active-window?lq=1)

EDIT2:
I spoke too early. I don't know why but above solution is not working reliably. So I am using Dmitry Alexandrov's solution, it works well except a glitch in my script.

```
   #!/bin/bash
   read __ __ TERM_PID < <(xprop _NET_WM_PID) &&\
   SH_PID=$(ps --ppid "$TERM_PID" -o pid=)
   mypid=$(echo $SH_PID | awk  ' { print $2 } ' )
   myid=$(ps $mypid |tail -n 1 |awk '{print $3}')
   if [[ $myid == "Sl" ]]
   then
   kill -STOP $mypid
   else
   kill -CONT $mypid
   fi
Note: Process STAT is not reliable, it doesn't always toggle between Sl and T, it sometimes takes different states such as `Ss+` `S<`
```

EDIT3:

This one works well

```
   #!/bin/bash
   read __ __ TERM_PID < <(xprop _NET_WM_PID) &&\
   SH_PID=$(ps --ppid "$TERM_PID" -o pid=)
   mypid=$(echo $SH_PID | awk  ' { print $2 } ' )
   myid=$(ps $mypid |tail -n 1 |awk '{print $3}')
   if [[ *$myid* == *"S"* ]]
   then
   kill -STOP $mypid
   else
   kill -CONT $mypid
   fi
```

Comment: Have you given the solutions in [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/q/508527/81372) a try?

Comment: @Glutanimate
yes, I tried that example too. It returns `gnome-terminal-` title only, it's parent process of all child bash processes

Comment: @Glutanimate
 **wininfo** also doesn't discriminate child PIDs in gnome-terminal. It only discriminates active windows but it doesn't print  their own PIDs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which window has current focus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25644/which-window-has-current-focus)

Comment: The bash console uses a pseudo terminal handled in the background by the Gnome (or other) terminal. I don't think you'll be able to get access to that data easily...

Comment: It's easy enough to get the PID of child bash processes for a Terminal, but the problem is distinguishing between multiple tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If terminal has only one shell process, I cannot see a problem.

```
read __ __ TERM_PID < <(xprop _NET_WM_PID) &&\
SH_PID=$(ps --ppid "$TERM_PID" -o pid=)
kill -STOP "$SH_PID"
```

Works for XTerm, should work for GNOME Terminal too, I believe.

Otherwise – if there may be more than one shell running under single terminal process (in several windows, tabs, regions, via multiplexer, etc), it’s not clear from the question, what do you want.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer close to a solution. I am confused that  **$SH_PID** returns two PIDS like `5535 5536` the latter is exact PID of the bash process. Though I haven't figured out how it works, I think I can handle the rest